# Using Singleton within the Android Room Library

Tags: android, design-patterns, android-room, android-architecture-components, android-livedata

I have always been told that using Singleton were bad. However, every example of the Android Room implementation seems to use the Singleton approach. Can someone please explain why is this the case?

Thanks

Comment: Using singleton isn't a bad practice. It can be a good practice for particular cases, such as instantiate a database (which looks like to be your case here). So why is it a good practice to use it to instantiate a database? A singleton on your database object prevents anyone from instantiating your database object twice, which could lead to tricky errors and poor performances.
It can be a good practice, just depends why you use it and how.

Comment: May you please give links about where you saw implementations of Android Room using Singleton?

Comment: Well their quite a few but this the one from [Google Code Lab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-room-with-a-view/index.html?index=..%2F..%2Findex#6)

Comment: The only reason why I'm against it is that I have always been told it never ideal to use them (Hard to tests, lead to memory leaks...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Singletons are considered evil because misusing them can make testing difficult. If the code being tested goes out and grabs a static singleton, then that singleton becomes difficult to mock for testing.

To mitigate the testing issue, your code should never *get* the singleton. Always receive it as a constructor parameter or have it injected by a DI framework. Of course, DI just moves the problem, because then the DI component becomes the singleton that your code reaches out and gets. But then you only have to figure out how to mock the DI component instead of a bunch of other things.

On Android, the `Application` is effectively a singleton, because only one instance is created per VM. So it's a good place to host other singletons like a DI component.

Answer (score 11):

There are two way

1 ) you should be use dagger 2

2) make method in abstract RoomDatabase class which are provided object of class

Example:

```
@Database(entities = { Repo.class }, version = 1)
public abstract class RepoDatabase extends RoomDatabase {

    private static final String DB_NAME = "repoDatabase.db";
    private static volatile RepoDatabase instance;

    static synchronized RepoDatabase getInstance(Context context) {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = create(context);
        }
        return instance;
    }

private RepoDatabase() {};

    private static RepoDatabase create(final Context context) {
        return Room.databaseBuilder(
            context,
            RepoDatabase.class,
            DB_NAME).build();
    }

    public abstract RepoDao getRepoDao();
}
```

Comment: Can you explain why the  getInstance() method is "static synchronized"?

Comment: synchronized because it would be possible to create two instances in multithreading scenario's. static should explain itself

Comment: How can I access the instance?

Comment: You can get access by this way :   RepoDatabase.getInstance(context)

Comment: @NikhilVadoliya - you forgot to add **public** for `getInstance()`. By default it's private